# Get Latest Entry from Database

Tags: php, sql, select, date

How can I get the latest entry by the latest DATE field from a MySQL database using PHP?

The rows will not be in order of date, so I can't just take the first or last row.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want the [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_order_by.asp) clause, and perhaps the [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html) clause.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] ORDER BY [dateColumn] DESC
```

If you want only the first row:

In T-SQL:

```
SELECT TOP(1) * FROM [Table] ORDER BY [dateColumn] DESC
```

In MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table` ORDER BY `dateColumn` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id1050031) and [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html#id2972920) clauses.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a unique recordid or date revised field you could key in on?  I always have at least an auto incrementing numeric field in addition to data created and date revised fields.  Are you sure there is nothing you can key in on?

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY recno DESC LIMIT 1;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date_revised DESC LIMIT 1;
```

So the PHP call would be:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date_revised DESC LIMIT 1");
```

-- Nicholas